# java multithreading. sharing data in a thread-safe manner

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized, static-variables

I'm programming a TCP Socket application in java and I have some doubt regards how to do it in a thread-save manner. 
In this eample, the  static method startServer(int port)  creates a passive TCP socket. In main, I wait for an incoming connection, that will be managed from a dedicated thread.

Firs of all, I would really like to understand the interaction between threads.

> Let A, B two instance of the same class:
>
> 1. Instance attributes of A are not visibile from B;
> 2. Static attributes are visible both from A and from B.
>
> Let T1 , T2 two threads of the same class:
>
> 1. Does the attributes visibility works in the same manner as with
>    instance?     In other words, only static attributes can be shared from
>    thread?
> 2. Non static attributes are always thread-safe?

In this code thread-safe?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MultithreadServer extends Thread 
    {
     private Socket client;
     private String nonStaticAttribute;
     private static volatile Vector<String> clientsVector;
    
     public MultithreadServer(Socket c, String enc)
        {client = c;
         nonStaticAttribute = new String("val=" + Math.random());}
    
    /** create a passive socket*/
    public static ServerSocket startServer() throws BindException, IOException
        {clientsVector= new Vector<String>();}

    public void run()
        {

        try
            {
            MultithreadServer.clientsVector.addElement(clientName); // Does this variable shared in a thread-safe way between threads? Vector in internally Synchronized
             while(true)
                {
                /** does this line print a different values for each thread? (the value that was assigned in the costructor?)
                Or all thread will display the same value (the value of the costructor of the last thread ? ) */
                System.out(nonStaticAttribute);
                Thread.sleep(1000);}
            }
        catch(IOException e)
            {}
            }
        }
        
    /** main */
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException
        { // Start del server
        myClass.startServer();
        myClass t1 = new myClass();
        t1.start();
        myClass t2 = new myClass();
        t2.start();
        ....
        myClass tn = new myClass();
        tn.start();
        }   

    }
```

If I have correctly understood, locals instances attributes are thread-safe, because they have their own state (in this case multiple threads works independently like multiple istances). 
In my opinion, also the use of static Vector is thread-save, but only because Vector is internally Synchronized. 
 
What's about if I use a non synchronized resource like a file?

```
public class myClass extends Thread {
    // same code as the other example
    private final static File file = new File("rubrica.txt");

    void run() {
    .....
    synchronized (file)
        {FileWriter fout= new FileWriter(file,true);
         fout.write("add some content at the end");
         fout.flush();
         fout.close();
        }
    }
```

I will really appreciate any help. 
I wish you a nice day :)

Comment: Answering your question about `A, B` -- no, mutlithreaded visibilty has nothing to do with visibility of class/instance members. Start with reading Oracle threads tutorial.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I've read documentation before post my question, but I really can't understand. According with documentation, all attributes (static and not) are visibles from all thread (to be precise, I can't find anything that say the opposite); in this case, why if I creates multiple clients with my code, each one works with it's own "Socket client", "BufferedReader input", ... ? Is this a case? I'm really confused @.@

Comment: If I got your question correctly, it's because each client uses its' dedicated socket (and associated `...Input` instances), since this is the way Sockets API is designed -- each network client is identified by a socket, two clients can share single socket, otherwise they will interfere which each other (reading each other data, etc).

Comment: @VictorSorokin Sorry, I don't speak english very well and probably I was not clear. That I need multiple active socket for multiple clients is clear... 
My question is regards visible of variables: "According with my runtime tests, this code seems to works well with multiple client (values of non-static attribute are different between the threads ==> like instance visibility), but from multithread documentation I assume that A and B should share also non-static attributes. In wich assertion am I wrong?"

Comment: Sorry, now I'm confused about new question. To me, it seems like you need to re-state it in main question section above using this guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @VictorSorokin ok, I've removed the useless line in my question

Comment: Synchronizing on the `File` object provides exclusion guarantees for all threads synchronizing on the same object, i.e. establish a safe protocol between all instances of `myClass` as they certainly do the synchronization. Since the field is `private`, we can assume that no-one else can use this object without synchronization, however, nothing prevents other classes from constructing a `new File("rubrica.txt")`, which is a distinct object, still represents the same file, so performing I/O with it could interfere. In the end, you are the one to say if such code could exist in your application.